# Override implicit conversion for existing types

Tags: c#

In my code I am handling emails sometimes as string `string emailA = "abc@abc.com"`. But most of the time an actual `MailAddress` object is passed around and handled. My question is can I implement an implicit conversion from string to MailAddress if I have no control over either type?

If this was an object implemented by me i could use this: `public static implicit operator MailAddress(string email) => new MailAddress(email);`

Comment: You can't make it implicit since you would need to modify the `MailAddress` class. You could inherit from it and add your implicit operators, but I don't really see the benefit in doing that. Another option is an extension method (`"foo@bar.com".ToMailAddress()`) but again that seems needlessly complicated. If your code is mixing `MailAddress` and `string` a lot, then it would likely be far cleaner to stop doing that and stick to one or the other.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. Why not just commit to everything being a MailAddress and using `.tostring()` where you absolutely need a string?

Comment: Implicit conversions should always be safe and never throw exceptions, so (_if it were allowed_) an implicit conversion from `MailAddress` to `string` would be okay (as a `MailAddress` object always contains a valid `Address` property), but there _should not_ be any implicit conversion from `string` to `MailAddress` because not all strings are valid e-mail addresses, hence the need for `TryParse` etc methods.

Comment: I'm connecting to different code, which doesnt use MailAddress. 
This is a generell question. I know how to "get around" this or that mixing types for the same value is not reccommended, but that was not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's currently not possible in C#.

---

You are not the only one who wants this feature: There's an open feature request in the C# language repository for "Extension Operators", which would allow you to define explicit and implicit conversion operators as extension methods.

- https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/515